# How to make POST requests with the FormData API

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, form-data, angularjs-fileupload

I want to pass the username and form_data object to the php file using http.post
when i pass only form_data it works my picture upload. but i want to pass some other information like username as well. please help me how to pass other data in http.post 
And here is my php file.

```
<?php include "connectdb.php";
    $data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $name=$dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->susername);
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $date=2;
        $path = 'fooditem/'. $_FILES['file']['name'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path)) {
           $query="INSERT INTO `login`(`id`,`type`,`img`) VALUES('".$name."','".$date."','".$_FILES['file']['name']."')";   
           if($dbhandle->query($query)){
               echo 'File Uploaded';
           }
           else
               echo 'File Uploaded But Not Saved';
        }
    }else{
     echo 'Some Error';
    }
```

```js
myapp.directive("fileInput",function($parse){
   return{
       link: function($scope,element,attrs){
           element.on("change",function(event){
               var files = event.target.files;
               $parse(attrs.fileInput).assign($scope, element[0].files);
               $scope.$apply();
               // console.log(files[0].name);
           });
       }
   } 
});
```

```
myapp.controller("myController",function($scope,$http){        
    $scope.signup = function(){

    var form_data = new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
            form_data.append('file',file);
        });
    $http.post("picupload.php",{'susername':$scope.susername,form_data})
      .then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
    })                
});
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="username" name="username">
<input type="file" file-input="files" accept="image/*" />
<input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" ng-click="signup()"
       name="signup_btn" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Comment: Is it ES6? if so you shoud see your "form_data" in $_POST in php, otherwise you should {'susername':$scope.susername, "form_data": form_data} and again it will be in $_POST

Answer (score 3):

You can add something like this:

```
 myapp.controller("myController",function($scope,$http){
        $scope.signup = function(){    
        var form_data = new FormData();
        angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
                form_data.append('file',file);
        });
        form_data.append('susername',$scope.susername);  // new line
        var config = {headers: { 'Content-type': undefined } };
        $http.post("picupload.php",form_data, config)
                .success(function(response){
                alert(response);
        });                
}
```

I'm not sure about PHP but after googling I found that in php 'susername' can retrieved as below:

```
$_POST['susername'];
```

Comment: And how to get susername is php file?

Comment: I'm not sure about PHP but after googling I found that in php 'susername' can retrieved as below:  
  
    $_POST['susername'];  give it a try and see.

Answer (score 2):

### How to make POST requests with the FormData API

When posting objects created by the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it is important to set the `Content-type` header to `undefined`.

```
$scope.signup = function(){
            
    var form_data = new FormData();
    angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
        form_data.append('file',file);
    });

    form_data.append('susername', $scope.susername);

    var config = {headers: { 'Content-type': undefined } };

    return $http.post("picupload.php",form_data, config)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
    });                
};
```

Also a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) can not be serialized into a [JSON string](http://www.json.org/) it must be sent by the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) alone. Append all necessary data to the FormData object.

When the [XHR send API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) posts an object created by the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it automatically sets the content type header to `multipart/form-data` with a proper [encapsulation boundary](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) and encodes the data using [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Normally the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) overrides the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) sets the content type header to `application/json`. Setting the content type header to `undefined` allows the XHR API the freedom to set the header properly.

---

## Update

On the server side use:

```
$_POST['susername'];
```

to receive the data item.

Comment: And how to pass $username