# Getting value null while uploading file through AngularJs in Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, forms, post, file-upload

When I am trying to upload a file using POST Request in Angular Js then I can not able to upload the file because it shows file value null

This is angular part **app.js**

```
$scope.submitForm = function(api_url , product){
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: enviroment_url + api_url,
        data: product,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        if(response.status == 200){
            toaster.pop('success', "Message", response.data.message, 3000, 'trustedHtml');
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        toaster.pop('error', "Message", response.data.message, 3000, 'trustedHtml');
    });
}
```

**form.blade.php**

```
<form id="myform">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title float-left" id="Heading">Add Product</h4>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name<span class="danger">*</span></label>
                <input class="form-control " ng-model="product.name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Product Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Product Image</label>
                <input type="file" file-model='product.img_url' class="form-control" id="upload" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" ng-model="product.description" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="modal-footer ">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submitForm('add-product', product)"
            class="btn btn-warning btn-lg " data-dismiss="modal"
            style="width: 100%;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>Add
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**fileController.php**

```
public function addProduct(Request $request){

        dd($request->all()); 
}
```

**OUTPUT** the result due to dd() function

```
array:1 [
  "{"name":"Allen","description":"Sint_dolores_ipsam_n","img_url":{}}" => null
]
```

Comment: The $http Service encodes JavaScript objects to JSON format, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. JSON format does not support files. File Blobs need to be sent directly or appended to [FormData objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) which are sent as `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make POST requests with the FormData API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43455357/5535245)

Answer (score -1):

Your `content type` in headers should be like this
`'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`

Comment: The `multipart/form-data` header needs a proper boundary. Read [How to make POST requests with the FormData API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43455357/5535245). With the AngularJS framework, it is important to set the content type header to `undefined` so that the FormData API sets the proper boundary.